# find total work hours by device

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a log table: `processlogmodel`

```
id      log_time               log_type device_id
1061    1/1/2016 9:08:45    PM  False   2
1062    1/1/2016 11:19:45   PM  False   2
1063    1/2/2016 8:44:46    AM  False   2
1064    1/2/2016 3:56:46    AM  True    3
1065    1/2/2016 12:51:46   AM  True    2
1066    1/1/2016 6:33:46    PM  False   2
1067    1/2/2016 8:20:46    AM  False   3
1068    1/2/2016 7:57:46    AM  True    1
1069    1/1/2016 6:21:46    PM  False   1
1070    1/2/2016 8:34:47    AM  False   2
1071    1/2/2016 12:18:47   AM  True    1
1072    1/1/2016 6:14:47    PM  True    3
1073    1/2/2016 8:21:47    AM  True    2
1074    1/2/2016 12:39:47   AM  False   3
1075    1/1/2016 11:23:47   PM  False   1
1076    1/1/2016 8:02:11    PM  True    1
1078    1/2/2016 4:02:12    AM  False   1
1079    1/1/2016 8:02:11    PM  True    2
1080    1/1/2016 10:02:11   PM  True    2
1081    1/1/2016 4:54:11    AM  False   2
1083    1/1/2016 5:47:11    AM  True    2
1084    1/2/2016 4:47:12    AM  False   2
1085    1/2/2016 8:39:12    AM  True    2
```

How can I find total work hours for each device?

**0** means *on* and **1** means *off*, I use sqlite3 and Python.

its just log model and i add record with log_type=0 for start working and log_type=1 for end work time for a device. 
i want to :
1. find continuous record by devices for calculate work duration
2. find total work hours by device.

Comment: Is there also date? or only hours? how can we know what day he logged

Comment: table definition please, the query is not complex but the low details makes it hard to understand it. If you want to try by your own check sql school (group by and aggregate functions) http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp and http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_functions.asp

Comment: Excpected results would by very helpful

Comment: And a person can be logged in more then 24 hours? I.E. log in in 1/1/2016 and out at 1/2/2016 ?

Comment: " And a person can be logged in more then 24 hours? I.E. log in in 1/1/2016 and out at 1/2/2016 ?"   answer is Yes.

Comment: can you explain the logic, so ... `id 1061 device2 starts work`... and then again id `1062 device2 starts work again` .. and then id `1063 device2 starts work again` ... id `1065 device2 stops work` ? .. so how would you summarize this ?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

this is my solution:

```
SELECT device_id, sum(sub) as total 
FROM (
    SELECT t1.device_id, strftime('%s', t2.log_time)-strftime('%s', t1.log_time) as sub 
    FROM app_processlogmodel AS t1 INNER JOIN app_processlogmodel AS t2
    WHERE t1.device_id = t2.device_id AND
    t1.log_type = 0 AND
    t2.log_type = 1 AND
    t2.log_time > t1.log_time
    GROUP BY t1.id HAVING min(strftime('%s', t2.log_time) - strftime('%s', t1.log_time))
    ORDER BY t1.device_id, t1.log_time
)
GROUP BY device_id
```

and it works :)